# Django: customusate m2m inline or class Meta for through model

Tags: django

If I want change label for InlineAdmin, I should set:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "One"
    verbose_name_plural = "Many"
```

for Model but usually it looks good as is.

Now I use [m2m Inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models), and labels look like "Mymodel1-mymodel2 relationships" fore many and "Mymodel1-mymodel2 relationship: MyModel1 mymodel2 object" for one. And I can't translate it, it's really frustrating me.
How I can fix this?

Upd1:
Im find that need add:

```
verbose_name = "One"
verbose_name_plural = "Many"
```

to AdminInline without Meta. And now label Many look good, but for one "One: MyModel1_mymodel2 object" still not good.

Comment: The text that goes there is the one that is defined in `__str__` or `__unicode__` method of the class. Override it to something readable and append PK or any other field from the Model.

Comment: @Andrey Shipilov, Yes! I'm freez some time, post like answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text that goes there is the one that is defined in **str** or **unicode** method of the class. Override it to something readable and append PK or any other field from the Model.